# DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'FormData'

Tags: flutter, dio

> I'm new in Flutter. When i try to upload data to the server i faced some problems like:
> 1.NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'friendsList' was called on null
> 2.DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'FormData'

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:data_collection/helperClass/testForAddButton.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

class AutoCompleteDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoCompleteDemoState createState() => _AutoCompleteDemoState();
}

class _AutoCompleteDemoState extends State<AutoCompleteDemo> {
  final hospitalNameEng = TextEditingController();
  final _serviceKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static List<String> friendsList = [];
  File imageFile;
  String servicejson;
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  //for camera dialogBox
  Future<void> _showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Make a Choice"),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Text("Gallery"),
                    onTap: () {
                      _openGallery(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Text("Camera"),
                    onTap: () {
                      _openCamera(context);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

//for image
  Widget _decideImageView() {
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return Text("No Image Selected");
    } else {
      Image.file(
        imageFile,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
      );
    }
    return Image.file(
      imageFile,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
    );
  }

//Dio part
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  Future postData() async {
    final String apiUrl = "MY_API";
    setState(() {
      servicejson = jsonEncode(friendsList);
    });

    String imageFileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
          filename: imageFileName, contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')),
      "type": "image/png"
    });

    dynamic allOfTheUploadData = {
      "name": hospitalNameEng,
      "Services": servicejson,
      "Image": formData,
    };
    var response = await dio.post(apiUrl,
        data: allOfTheUploadData,
        options: Options(headers: {
          "accept": "*/*",
          "Authorization": "Bearer accresstoken",
          "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        }));

    return response.data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:5.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: hospitalNameEng,
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(hintText: 'Hospital Name In English'),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            ),
            //service
            Container(
              child: Form(
                key: _serviceKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Services',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      ..._getServices(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //camera
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _showChoiceDialog(context);
                      },
                      child: Text("Select Image"),
                    ),
                    _decideImageView(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //send to server
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          await postData().then((value) {
                            print(value);
                          });
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text("Submit"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //services
  List<Widget> _getServices() {
    List<Widget> friendsTextFieldsList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < friendsList.length; i++) {
      friendsTextFieldsList.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: FriendTextFields(i)),
            SizedBox(
              width: 16,
            ),
            // we need add button at last friends row only
            _addRemoveButton(i == friendsList.length - 1, i),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
    return friendsTextFieldsList;
  }

  Widget _addRemoveButton(bool add, int index) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (add) {
          // add new text-fields at the top of all friends textfields
          friendsList.insert(0, null);
        } else
          friendsList.removeAt(index);
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: (add) ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Icon(
          (add) ? Icons.add : Icons.remove,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //gallery
  _openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      imageFile = picture;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  //Camera
  _openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      imageFile = picture;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

> For add button which i used in Widget _getservices() class

```
import 'package:autocomplete_textfield/autocomplete_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../players.dart';

class FriendTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  FriendTextFields(this.index);
  final GlobalKey<_FriendTextFieldsState> serviceKey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  _FriendTextFieldsState createState() => _FriendTextFieldsState();
}

class _FriendTextFieldsState extends State<FriendTextFields> {
  GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<Division>> key = new GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController _serviceController;
  AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField;

  void _loadData() async {
    await PlayersViewModel.loadPlayers();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
    _serviceController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _serviceController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
      var _AutoCompleteDemoState;
      _serviceController.text = _AutoCompleteDemoState.friendsList[widget.index] ?? '';
    });
    var _AutoCompleteDemoState;
  
    return TextFormField(
      controller:
          _serviceController, // save text field data in friends list at index
      // whenever text field value changes

      onChanged: (v) => _AutoCompleteDemoState.friendsList[widget.index] = v,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a unique code: Service Name\''),
      validator: (v) {
        if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please enter something';
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Dio can't parse `FormData` instance if it is wrapped by another object or if you use nested `FormData`, so instead of doing this:

```dart
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
      filename: imageFileName, contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')),
  "type": "image/png"
});

dynamic allOfTheUploadData = {
  "name": hospitalNameEng,
  "Services": servicejson,
  "Image": formData,
};
```

do this:

```dart
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  "name": hospitalNameEng,
  "Services": servicejson,
  "Image": {
      "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
          filename: imageFileName, contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')),
      "type": "image/png"
  },
});
```

or something like that but but you must not wrapped `FormData` with another object. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/881)

- Assuming that:

  1. You are new in flutter.
  2. You have only two dart files.
  3. Only one class has external dependacies.

If the affirmations above are right, it is not necessary to use Provider, you can pass `friendsList` and the current index to the `FriendTextFields`: `FriendTextFields(i, friendsList)`. And in the second file:

```dart
class FriendTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final List<String> friendsList;
  FriendTextFields(this.index, this.friendsList);
  final GlobalKey<_FriendTextFieldsState> serviceKey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  _FriendTextFieldsState createState() => _FriendTextFieldsState();
}
```

and

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {

      _serviceController.text = widget.friendsList[widget.index] ?? '';
    });
    return TextFormField(
      controller:
          _serviceController, // save text field data in friends list at index
      // whenever text field value changes

      onChanged: (v) => widget.friendsList[widget.index] = v,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a unique code: Service Name\''),
      validator: (v) {
        if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please enter something';
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you sir, can you tell me how initialized this variable?

Comment: Initializing variable means assigning a value to that variable for the first time. I can't tell you how to inititialize your variable because i don't know which value you want to assign to it. but for exemple if you have a class called `_HospitalState` you have to do this `var hn = _HospitalState();`.

Comment: And don't forget that a class or object name preceded by a underscore "_" is private and can't be used outside of the file in which it is declared.

Comment: if do this as like you say then its doesn't work. i try to add _HospitalState in initialize but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: sorry sir, it's my mistake, now i edit my question. plz check now it's not _HospitalState it's _AutoCompleteDemoState which comes from my main.dart file

Comment: look at my modification, normally it should work.

Comment: no sir, your last modification didn't work, there has a widget _addRemoveButton for add remove button. after using your edition this widget didn't work

Comment: now its showing DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [413]

Comment: the 413 error code means that the file you want to upload is larger than the size that is supported by your server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      // Here:
      var _AutoCompleteDemoState;
      _serviceController.text = _AutoCompleteDemoState.friendsList[widget.index] ?? '';
    });
    var _AutoCompleteDemoState;
  
    return TextFormField(
      controller:
          _serviceController, // save text field data in friends list at index
      // whenever text field value changes

      onChanged: (v) => _AutoCompleteDemoState.friendsList[widget.index] = v,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a unique code: Service Name\''),
      validator: (v) {
        if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please enter something';
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

Here, you haven't assigned any value to the `_AutoCompleteDemoState` variable. So, it is null. I don't know where it is coming from exactly. But it needs to be assigned some value.

Also, as I understand you're trying to access a variable inside another Widget. This can be done by passing the data to the next Widget as follows:
What you were doing is passing the wrong data. Instead of passing the index, I would suggest that you pass this.

```dart
class FriendTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  final String friend;
  FriendTextFields(this.friend);
  final GlobalKey<_FriendTextFieldsState> serviceKey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  _FriendTextFieldsState createState() => _FriendTextFieldsState();
}
```

However, I would very much recommend that you use a Provider for accessing such things. It will help you a lot. Check the Provider documentation over [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). You can learn more about Provider over [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd).

Comment: Sir ,there i use index for, when i click add button its create new textfield. if i use friend then what i passed in main file. ```List<Widget> _getServices() {
    List<Widget> friendsTextFieldsList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < friendsList.length; i++) {
      friendsTextFieldsList.add(Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: FriendTextFields(i)),
            SizedBox(width: 16,),
            _addRemoveButton(i == friendsList.length - 1, i),],),)); }
    return friendsTextFieldsList; }```

Comment: You cannot comment code and expect me to understand it. Anyways, as I said if you'd like to do whatever you intend to do, you need access to the `friendsList` variable in multiple Widgets. This can be done using Providers. Please refer to the examples in the link.

Comment: I hope you didn't find that comment aggressive. My point was that, in order to make me understand your point, you need to put the code in the Question itself to give it proper formatting. Another point was that, without the use of Providers or any other state management tool, you'll find it difficult to achieve what you need. So, please have a look into that as well.

Comment: my code are all i give in the question. there i used 2 dart class and yes , now i try to do this by providers. if faced any problem by using providers i knock you.

Comment: Great!!! Sure, let the community know if you face any problems, they will be ready to help.

Comment: now its showing DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [413]

Comment: It maybe because of internet error on your device or a server error. It's not a problem with Dio as such. Try checking on different devices and different networks. Also, if the issue persists, please create a new issue.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413) may be the reason. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

There was the same error because the Logging Interceptor, which tried to json.encode my FormData.

working code just:

```
var file = File(path);
var fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename: fileName),
});

Response resp = await dio.post(endpoint, data: formData);
```